# VB.NET running website project in debug mode & avoiding .dlls

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a .NET Framework 2 project successfully compiling in VS 2010 which is great. It's a working project which has had alot of tinkering over a longtime. I'm looking forward to sorting it all out. Currently when I 'Start Debugging' and add break points I run into a small probably common issue.

Basically my application runs off .DLL files which are made from .vb files in the application. So I cannot set breakpoints on these .vb files only on the .aspx files which are not bundled into the .dll files.

Now in the past when creating a standard vb project I can easily debug the server stuff. I was wondering how I can push the vb website project to run off of the .vb files and to ignore the .dll files completely, just for the time being.

thank you for any assistance you give me.

Regards,

Comment: Are these dlls used as dependencies in your project?

Comment: They are required when the project is rolled out. While I am working onit though I would like to be able to work with the .vb files by using breakpoints and debugging facilities so not using any of the .dlls. If I delete the .dlls from the BIN folder and run the project it breaks. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you confirmed that the DLLs are used as references and are required for your code to run. The only way to go around it is to include the VB files you mentioned (the actual projects is better) into your solution. Make sure you change the references to point to projects instead of the DLLs.